# Tag random flagged lines with XML like tag

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with some random lines flagged with `%`, how to tag all the flagged content with a xml like tag.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
tt gs sdf 
% sdjfsg
% sdfsdf

sdfsdf

% sdfsd
% rewerwe
```

**TO:**

```
tt gs sdf 
<TAG>sdjfsg
sdfsdf</TAG>

sdfsdf

<TAG>sdfsd
rewerwe</TAG>
```

Comment: Use the `sed` solution instead of mine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give 'sed' a chance...

```
sed -ri ':x;$!{N;bx};s/% ([^\n]*)(\n|$)/<tag>\1<\/tag>\n/g;s/<\/tag>\n<tag>/\n/g;s/\n$//' tst.txt
```

This will tag your file in place.

Explanation:

1. `:x;$!{N;bx}` --> globbing file to one bufferline
2. `s/% ([^\n]*)(\n|$)/<tag>\1<\/tag>\n/g` --> tagging all lines beginning with '% '
3. `s/<\/tag>\n<tag>/\n/g` --> delete unneeded tags (if closing tag followed by opening tag)
4. `s/\n$//` --> delete unneeded newline at end of file

Eventually it's possible to do it even shorter but this was the first straight-forward way I could imagine.